# java.io.IOException: Media was not found error while attaching a screenshot to extent report

Tags: selenium, automation, ioexception, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

When I tried to attach a screenshot captured and saved in selenium project to extent test automation report it gives me an error saying that ***java.io.IOException: Media was not found at [C:\Users\Suresh\git\BasicFuncTesting\test-output\Screenshot\imageOneBrokenTest.png]***

I have given my image path as below.

```
String imagePath = "C:\\Users\\Suresh\\git\\BasicFuncTesting\\test-output\\Screenshot\\imageOneBrokenTest.png";
```

I have used 2 methods as below to attach this screenshot but both methods gives me the same error.

```
logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(imagePath, "Fail");

logger.fail("Screenshot", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(imagePath).build());
```

Here logger is the ExtentTest object.

Comment: try to use absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully generate my extent report with the captured screenshot by setting the variable values as below.

```
    String imagePath = "C:/Users/Suresh/git/BasicFuncTesting/BasicFuncTesting/test-output/Screenshot/1587494732758.png";

try {
           logger.fail("Screenshot", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(imagePath).build());                    
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```